# Codeberg REST API calls issues

Tags: html, ajax, rest, cors

I have this basic example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var url = 'https://codeberg.org/api/v1/repos/tok1n/fs_test/contents?access_token=%20%20b9916af6acd23f37e9bd165f3349e2b8aaa135bf';
console.log("1");
// get auto-generated page 
$.ajax({url: url}).then(function(html) {
    console.log("2");

    // create temporary DOM element
    var document = $(html);
    console.log(html);

    // find all links ending with .pdf 
    document.find('a[href$=".pdf"]').each(function() {
        console.log("4");

        var pdfName = $(this).text();
        var pdfUrl = $(this).attr('href');

        // do what you want here 
        console.log(pdfName);
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Where I generated the access token (`https://codeberg.org/api/v1/repos/tok1n/fs_test/contents?access_token=%20%20b9916af6acd23f37e9bd165f3349e2b8aaa135bf`) with `repos` access,and can see that when I call:

`curl -X 'GET' \ 'https://codeberg.org/api/v1/repos/tok1n/fs_test/contents?access_token=%20%20b9916af6acd23f37e9bd165f3349e2b8aaa135bf' \ -H 'accept: application/json'`

> [{"name":"index.html","path":"index.html","sha":"391e76cb49021e6d308b67b49c0f82f09e703273","last_commit_sha":"3c9a4327291c76617c4a080c81863194d7df1dea","type":"file".......

which is just the contents here: [fs_test](https://codeberg.org/tok1n/fs_test)

So I am correctly getting the JSON, checking the console at the [page](https://tok1n.codeberg.page/fs_test/) gives me a CORS error.

I believe the page is on the same domain as the API call, or is there something I am missing here?

It might be my misunderstanding of CORS that is the issue here, but aren't these access tokens granting the client permission?

If not, what are they used for when CORS is enabled?

Thanks